# Visual studio 2010 C# debugging MS Dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dataset

I am using MSDatasets to link to a server (on local network), method are as below:

1) Right click the project -> add new item

2) Select dataset and rename

3) Open server explorer and add new connection to server on local network

4) Once connected to the local server, drag tables needed into the datasets

5) the dataset/ table could be called from classes in the program

Everything worked fine. But sometimes the server might be down for some reasons, and the program thus fail to connect and prompts a error message "A unhandle win32 exception occurred in program.exe......." and then quits the program itself.

How can a prompt the user with a more user-friendly message (e.g. "sorry the server is down, please try again later") when the connection to the server fails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time a DataSet object really connects to the server is when you call your Adapter's `Update()` or `Fill()` functions (assuming you're using typed approach only). You could place those pieces inside try/catch blocks to achieve what you want.

If you are using drag-n-drop from Data Sources window, you should have these lines inside your Form's `Load` event handler and navigation toolbar's `SaveButton_Click` (or something like that) event handler.